# Meaning of "know life for what it is"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *know life for what it is* mean? Maybe it means something like *know what life is really like*?

> Always to look life in the face and to **know it for what it is**.

Comment: That's exactly what it means. To know what it truly is, rather than how it appears or how others think of it.

Comment: I see someone else thinks this is "General Reference". Personally, I think it's an off-topic invitation to start a discussion on a philosophical issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "for what" a phrase?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60480/is-for-what-a-phrase)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the question is not a philosophical inquiry, merely a question about the meaning of an English sentence. As apparent in comments to duplicate I linked to (which ought to be reopened and given a simple answer) OP didn't understand *what it is* as the complement of preposition *for*.

Comment: @jwpat7: OP's grasp of basic English seems quite limited, and I don't think ELU should be used as a beginner's introduction to ESL *unless* the specific point raised involve something interesting about usage. And given Pitarou's first comment here should have enlightened OP anyway, I also don't see why he re-asked about *"for what"*, or why you suggested closing *this* as a duplicate of that second question. We're all entitled to our own opinions, of course, but mine is that neither of these questions should be here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I hadn't realized (before checking times) that this question is 6 hours older than the other, and thought it was vice versa. Yes, Pitarou's comment was timely, and so straightforward that OP should have gone away satisfied. I guess we'll see whether both questions or only one get deleted.

Comment: @jwpat7: I wouldn't want to overstate my antipathy here. I don't really mind such questions if they're simply answered with a comment and briskly closed. I doubt I'd vote to actually *delete* either unless I was just in a snarky mood at the time. I think these are issues where one just has to wait and see if anything like a "consensus" arises within ELU as to what type of questions we want to see, and how we should deal with the rest.

Comment: @jwpat7: The question you linked to as a possible duplicate, is now closed as "Not a real question", of which I agree. I'm not sure I agree that this question here sould be closed though, as beyond clarifying the meaning of the phrace, it would be interresting to also get some historic background on how this kind of wording originated. Maybe it would be better to expand the question to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face the reality of life, and don't think it's easy to live. Life is cruel, you just have to live with it...

You should not think you get anything for free in life. If you do, it's a bonus - never expect it.